# Searching an array for given number

Tags: java, arrays

Write a program that creates an array of 1000 random numbers in the range 1 – 5000. Then ask the user for a
value between and 5000, and search the array until you either find the value or determine that the value is
not in the array. Print a message indicating whether or not the value was found, and how many numbers you
had to look at before you found the value (or determined that it was not there).

For some reason I keep getting "Value not found" when regardless of my input. I cannot figure out what I did wrong. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Array 
{ 
    int y = 5000; 
    int x; 
    int values[] = new int[1000]; 
    Array() 
    { 
        Random rg = new Random(); 
        for (int x=0;x<values.length;x++) 
            values[x]=rg.nextInt(y+1); 

        Arrays.sort(values); 
    } 

    public int findNumber(int val) 
    { 
        int s=0, r = values.length; 
        int x=0; 
        while(true) 
        { 
            x++; 
            if (values[(r+s)/2]==val) 
                return x; 
            else if (val > values[(r+s)/2]) 
                s = (r+s)/2 + 1; 
            else 
                r = (r+s)/2 - 1; 
            if (s>r) 
                return -1; 

        } 

    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        Array fN = new Array(); 
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.println("Enter whole between 1 and 5000."); 
        int a = kb.nextInt(); 
        if (fN.findNumber(a)>0)
            System.out.println("Found in " + fN.findNumber(a) + " tries."); 
        else 
            System.out.println("Value not found!"); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Please read this: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0):

Not going to help you debug fully, just some hints for you:

First, probably not very closely related to your problem but still worth looking at: Generating by `rg.nextInt(y + 1)` is going to give you random from 0 to 5001, I believe you want `rg.nextInt(y) + 1` instead.

And I have tried your code after fixing the previous minor issue. It worked for me.  I don't see any problem.  However, what I am suspecting is, because you are generating 1000 random numbers which is possible to duplicate, if you simply input any number to search, it may not fall into that 1000 numbers you generated.  I have updated your code a bit so that you can take a look on what is generated, and use one of the result as your search input. It should work:

```
    Random rg = new Random();
    for (int x=0;x<values.length;x++) {
        int r = rg.nextInt(y) + 1;
        System.out.println("Random number: " + r);
        values[x]=r;
    }

    Arrays.sort(values);
```

(Just for your interest, the probability that you input a number that is in the previously-generated 1000 random numbers is around 1 - (4999/5000) ^ 1000 which is only around 18%.  That's why you may frequently get "value not found" message